# Command ExtractAppIntentsMetadata failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: swift, ios17, xcode15, macos-sonoma, deriveddata

I'm using xcode 15.0.1. When I try to build my project in this xcode, I'm getting `Command ExtractAppIntentsMetadata failed with a nonzero exit code` error. THe work around to change the derived data location to custom as mentioned in apple forum https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731439?answerId=767814022#767814022 will cause unintentional changes in xcconfig files. So, i need to discard all files while commiting the changes.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This issue should be fixed on the next Xcode 15.3.

**Old Answer**

If you're not using AppIntents in your app, you can disable auto-linking AppIntents by including the following build setting in your app target. With this, Xcode will truly skip Extract App Intents Metadata process and build will continue as usual.

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(inherited) -Xfrontend -disable-autolink-framework -Xfrontend AppIntents
```

Comment: unfortunately i'm using appintents extension in my project

Comment: Have you tried to use Xcode 15.3 beta? I've personally tried it on my project and the error is not happening anymore.